# xskakget fails with styleC

Tags: chess, xskak

I'm trying to print chessboard after some moves. For that I'm using `xskakget` to get the move number and print it as caption. It is working fine as long as I use the default style or `styleA` for `\mainline` command. If I use `styleC` to print chess moves in tabular form, xskakget is failing for `opennr`. I'm getting the error missing $ inserted. What am I missing ? The minimal working example is here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame\mainline[style=styleC]{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6}

\xskakset{moveid=2b}\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style key changes commands globally (I don't remember exactly why, but probably to avoid problems with tabular styles where cells create groups) so after your `\mainline` styleC is still active and so `\xskakget{opennr}` fails.

To quote the documentation:

> `opennr` contains the code to print the number like the package skak
>   would do it if you start or continue a game with this move.

That means it contains formatting informations. That's not really a problem as long as this formatting information contains only things like dots or font switches but with styleC it contains a tabbing command - and this command gives an error outside tabbing.

So when using opennr you should make sure a style is active that works in the current context (and looks like you want it to look).

E.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document} \show\blackopen 
\newchessgame\mainline[style=styleC]{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6}

\xskakset{style=styleB}%
\mainlinestyle %to activate the style
\xskakset{moveid=2b}\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}
\end{document}
```

You can also try out if it works if the style commands are not changed globally. But then you will have to add braces around the \mainline command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\xskak@do@copystyleitem[2]{% 
 \ifcsname #1beforeblack\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2whiteopen\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1whiteopen\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2blackopen\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1blackopen\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2beforewhite\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1beforewhite\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2beforeblack\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1beforeblack\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2afterwhite\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1afterwhite\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2afterblack\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1afterblack\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2beforenumber\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1beforenumber\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2opencommands\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1opencommands\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2closecommands\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1closecommands\endcsname
  %% two specific xskak command for the comments:
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2xskak@beforecomment\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1xskak@beforecomment\endcsname
  \expandafter\let
     \csname #2xskak@beforeNAG\expandafter\endcsname
     \csname #1xskak@beforeNAG\endcsname
 \else
  \PackageError{xskak}{style template #1 doesn't exist!}{}%
 \fi}
\makeatother 
%

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
{\mainline[style=styleC]{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6}}%group around mainline

\xskakset{moveid=2b}\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Surya, here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\title{xskak Dua Kolom}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{Botvinnik -- Smyslov} \\
    \textit{World Championship Match (17)} \\
    \textit{Moscow 1957} \\
    Gr\"{u}nfeld Defence
\end{center}

\newchessgame
\xskakset{style=styleC}

\mainline{1. Nf3 Nf6 2. g3 g6 3. c4 c6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. Nc3 O-O 6. d4 d5 7. cxd5
cxd5 8. Ne5 b6}
\[ \showboard \]
A satisfactory way of developing.  After {\variation[invar]{8... Nc6 9. Nxc6
bxc6}} Black would be saddled with a weak pawn at c6.

\mainline{9. Bg5 Bb7 10. Bxf6 Bxf6 11. O-O}

In the variation {\variation[invar]{11. e4 dxe4 12. Nxe4 Bxe5 13. dxe5 Nd7
14. f4 Nc5}} Black has a good game.

\mainline{11... e6 12. f4}

If {\variation[invar]{12. e4 Nc6 13. exd5} (\variation[invar]{13. Nxc6 Bxc6
14. exd5 exd5}) \variation[outvar]{13... Nxe5 14. dxe5 Bxe5 15. dxe6 Bxg2 16.
exf7+ Rxf7 17. Kxg2 Bxc3 18. bxc3 Qxd1 19. Rfxd1 Rc8 20. Rd3 Rc4}}, and Black
can successfully battle for a draw in the rook ending.

\end{document}
```